# Is this the site for "How to safely profit from violating copyright" questions?

Tags: discussion, legal

Specifically, [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33420/modding-and-copyright).

Note that the two highest upvoted answers, including the accepted one, both agree that yes, the proposed scheme to avoid being caught for profiting from violating copyright is good and would work to avoid prosecution, while still allowing the user to get paid.

*Are methods of getting away with a crime the sort of **expert knowledge** we really want to be gathering and archiving on this site?  Should we be accepting questions about where to hide bodies?  What about how to profitably engage in money laundering?*

Comment: No. (Apparently I can't just post "No" as a comment or an answer, and need more text.)

Comment: I tried the same thing.

Comment: I'm just baffled that the question hasn't been closed.  My close vote on it has already expired, and the question is still active enough to remain on the front page.  Is there anything that can be done at this stage?

Comment: Regardless of the intent of the asker, the fundamental question in that question is "Can the developer of a game be held liable for content that modders distribute?", which seems to be a valid question.

Comment: @Tetrad Agreed, that part of the question seems valid.  Would anyone object if I edited the question to only ask that?  (Removing the "M==P" and "How can M avoid being caught" portions of the question, which are more ethically difficult to justify).  Bearing in mind that the question's upvoted and accepted answer is primarily answering those latter questions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold

Comment: Do it. (Ah comment limit again!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When faced with a question asking about the likelihood of getting caught for knowingly enacting a criminal scheme, the question should be edited to remove the criminal scheme context, and to remove the "would I get caught" portion of the question.

In this case, the original question was (paraphrased) "If I anonymously released a mod for my own commercial game, and that mod contained copyrighted assets to which I had no rights, could I be caught?"  The edited question was turned around into "Is a game's author liable for copyright infringement in a mod which he didn't release".

As a general rule (which I know that I personally forget much too often!):  Don't be shy about editing other people's questions in order to make the site better.  Questions here aren't primarily about helping individuals (although they're about that too!), but are mostly about helping make the Internet at large a better, more useful place for everyone, by archiving great answers to common questions.  If you see a bad question and think you can edit it into a good question, absolutely do it!  :D

Comment: I've tried to paraphrase the comments above, and distill them down into a full answer that can be voted on and (maybe) accepted, just to finish off this question.  Please, anybody else feel free to post a different summary/answer or edit this one.   I'll wait a few days and then accept whatever has the most votes.  :)